# Can I put "SELECT result with multiple rows and multiple column" as function parameters?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to write a common function to convert SELECT/table result as text/jsonb
Convert

```
SELECT COALESCE(jsonb_agg(tmp)::text, '[]') FROM (
  SELECT id, balance FROM student LIMIT 5) AS tmp
```

to

```
SELECT my_to_json_string((SELECT id, balance FROM student LIMIT 5));
```

Expect:

```
[{"id": 21543, "balance": 80}, {"id": 21542, "balance": 100}, {"id": 21541, "balance": 5980}, {"id": 21540, "balance": 10}, {"id": 21539, "balance": 15}]`
```

Can I?
If not, what should I do to avoid repeat `COALESCE(jsonb_agg(tmp)::text, '[]') FROM (...) as tmp` so often?

Comment: no, you cannot, that's why you are asking....

Comment: Can you make your question a [mre] ? (Which includes leaving out the '....' in your question, example input, example desired output)

Comment: what do you mean by avoiding repeat `COALESCE(jsonb_agg(tmp_...` ?

Comment: @eshirvana Mostly I will write functions to return json string to server(I used Common Lisp/Hunchensock), therefore I used `COALESCE` so often in most functions

Comment: What happened when you tried to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE  FUNCTION build_details( mysqlquery text )
RETURNS jsonb AS $$
  DECLARE
    c jsonb;
  BEGIN
    EXECUTE format('SELECT COALESCE(jsonb_agg(tmp)::text, ''[]'') FROM (%s) as tmp', mysqlquery) INTO c;
    RETURN c;
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

To call this pass sql as a string

```
select * from build_details('SELECT * FROM foo LIMIT 5');
              build_details               
------------------------------------------
 [{"i": 1, "s": "f"}, {"i": 2, "s": "s"}]
(1 row)
```

Answering the question in comments regarding performance.
Yes, it would be slower.
To measure it, first turn on the nested statement analyzer.

```
load 'auto_explain'; 
set auto_explain.log_min_duration=0; 
set auto_explain.log_nested_statements=ON; 
SET auto_explain.log_analyze = true;
set client_min_messages=DEBUG;
```

Now let's run it.

```
explain analyze SELECT COALESCE(jsonb_agg(tmp)::text, '[]') FROM ( SELECT * FROM foo LIMIT 5) as tmp;
LOG:  duration: 0.030 ms  plan:
Query Text: explain analyze SELECT COALESCE(jsonb_agg(tmp)::text, '[]') FROM ( SELECT * FROM foo LIMIT 5) as tmp;
Aggregate  (cost=0.15..0.17 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.029..0.029 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Subquery Scan on tmp  (cost=0.00..0.14 rows=5 width=60) (actual time=0.008..0.009 rows=2 loops=1)
        ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..0.09 rows=5 width=36) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=2 loops=1)
              ->  Seq Scan on foo  (cost=0.00..22.70 rows=1270 width=36) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=2 loops=1)
                                                     QUERY PLAN                                                     
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=0.15..0.17 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.029..0.029 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Subquery Scan on tmp  (cost=0.00..0.14 rows=5 width=60) (actual time=0.008..0.009 rows=2 loops=1)
         ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..0.09 rows=5 width=36) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=2 loops=1)
               ->  Seq Scan on foo  (cost=0.00..22.70 rows=1270 width=36) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=2 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.042 ms
 Execution time: 0.143 ms
(6 rows)
```

vs

```
explain analyze select * from build_details('SELECT * FROM foo  LIMIT 5');
LOG:  duration: 0.043 ms  plan:
Query Text: SELECT COALESCE(jsonb_agg(tmp)::text, '[]') FROM (SELECT * FROM foo  LIMIT 5) as tmp
Aggregate  (cost=0.15..0.17 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.041..0.041 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Subquery Scan on tmp  (cost=0.00..0.14 rows=5 width=60) (actual time=0.007..0.009 rows=2 loops=1)
        ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..0.09 rows=5 width=36) (actual time=0.006..0.007 rows=2 loops=1)
              ->  Seq Scan on foo  (cost=0.00..22.70 rows=1270 width=36) (actual time=0.005..0.006 rows=2 loops=1)
LOG:  duration: 0.297 ms  plan:
Query Text: explain analyze select * from build_details('SELECT * FROM foo  LIMIT 5');
Function Scan on build_details  (cost=0.25..0.26 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.296..0.296 rows=1 loops=1)
                                                 QUERY PLAN                                                  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Function Scan on build_details  (cost=0.25..0.26 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.296..0.296 rows=1 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.024 ms
 Execution time: 0.385 ms
(3 rows)
```

My guess is that with enough volume the difference will be negligible.
Most of it is coming from the planning.
But you really need to check this out in your case and needs.

Comment: Good question.
I am editing my answer to clarify that

Comment: Sure you can. You can modify the function to accept variadic and loop through it to construct your query. Consider also using custom aggregation if you go this way, it seems that you have more complicated requirements then initially thought, see @Julius Tuskenis answer.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding

```
SELECT my_to_json_string((SELECT id, balance FROM student LIMIT 5));
```

I think sub-select should return single value, I don't think there's a trick to make PostgreSQL accept this syntax.

It seem to me you can accomplish what you want by introducing a custom aggregate:

```
create or replace function jsonify_add(jsonb, anyelement) returns jsonb
language sql
as $$
select $1 || to_jsonb($2);
$$;

create or replace function jsonify_final(jsonb) returns text
language sql
as $$
select coalesce($1::text, '[]');
$$;

CREATE AGGREGATE jsonify (anyelement)
(
    sfunc = jsonify_add,
    stype = jsonb,
    finalfunc = jsonify_final,
    initcond = '[]'
);
```

You may use it like:

```
select jsonify( emp ) from employee as emp;
```

Returning:

```
[{"name": "Barry", "number": 1, "surname": "White"}, {"name": "Wayne", "number": 2, "surname": "Black"}]
```